# Why can't I cd to this file?

Tags: command-line

When I execute following command:

`cd ./avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb`

or

`cd '/home/ravi/avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb'`

I get this error message:

`bash: cd: /home/ravi/Downloads/20120409121148448001.pdf: Not a directory`

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: As ephsmith said, these are not directories. To open them, use `gnome-open FILE` (replacing `FILE` with the file you want to open).

Comment: If trying to install try `sudo dpkg -i avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb` go to dash and type `avast`  click the link saying "Click here to obtain license key" and follow the rest of the on screen prompts

Comment: @ephsmith Put that as the answer.

Comment: @lkjoel You can post that as the answer too, both are correct.

Comment: @damien Yours is correct too.

Comment: If no-one posts it as an answer I will and I will steal all your reputation :+

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to **open any file from terminal**, you should issue command like

  `gnome-open ~/Downloads/photo.rar`

Here, `photos.rar` is file I want to open in the directory `~/Downloads/`.

BTW, `~`is used for user's home directory. `~/Downloads/photo.rar` will be interpreted like `/home/USER_NAME/Downloads/photo.rar`.

- if you are **trying to install `.deb` file**, you should issue

  `sudo dpkg -i /home/ravi/avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb`

also, this can be done like this,

```
cd /home/ravi/
sudo dpkg -i avast4workstation_1.3.0-2_i386.deb
```

remember you can use `cd ~` instead `cd /home/ravi/`.

- if you want **to *execute* a file which is in current directory**, then you should use

  `./FILE_NAME.sh`

Here `FILE_NAME.sh` can be any executable file.

***Note**: if path contains special characters like, spaces you should put it between single quote like `'/home/ravi/avast4workstation 1.3.0-2 i386.deb'` or you should escape special characters like `/home/ravi/avast4workstation\ 1.3.0-2\ i386.deb`*

*Hope I haven't confused you.*

Answer (score 1):

`cd` is a shell command to change to a directory, so it would not work to try to change directories into a file. If you tried to open these the same way you open a file in a file manager, you would have to use this:

```
gnome-open FILE
```

What that does is that it opens `FILE` using the default program associated with the type of that file.